# Writing a list of lists from a specific column in csv in python

Tags: python

I have a list of lists as below.
a = [[1,2,3], [2,3,4], [3,4,5]]

I also have a separate list of names
names = ['Ann', 'john', 'smith']

Now I want to write this into a csv file as below

```
1st row: Ann,1,2,3
2nd row: john,2,3,4
3rd row: smith,3,4,5
```

I am currently using;

```
with open(output_file, 'w') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerows(a)
```

However, it does not do the job I want as it always starts from the first column, instead of the second column. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open(output_file, 'w') as f:
   f.write('\n'.join([elem[0]+','+str(elem[1]).strip('[').strip(']') for elem in zip(names,a)]))
```

Try this.

Answer (score 1):

The key point to understand here is that you want to process your list *in parallel*. This can easily be accomplished by using the built-in function `zip`. It takes an list of iterables, and yields the *n*-th element of each iterable as a tuple. You can then format your lines by using `str.format`:

```
names = ['Ann', 'john', 'smith']
sublists = [[1,2,3], [2,3,4], [3,4,5]]

with open(output_file, 'w') as file:
    for name, sublist in zip(names, sublists):
        row = '{},{},{},{}'.format(name, *sublist)
        file.write(row)
```

Note if your lists are different sizes, you may want to look into using [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest).

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("output_file", 'w') as f:
    f.write("\n".join([','.join(map(str, [name] + extra)) for name, extra in zip(name, extras)])
```